# How to change the definition of VWAP's isNewPeriod switch to make it 3 days long but starting 2 days ago?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Here's the original `isNewPeriod` switch from the v5 VWAP indicator:

```
isNewPeriod = switch anchor
    // Irrelevant lines.
    "Session"   => timeframe.change("D")
    // Irrelevant lines.
    => false
```

Normal VWAP starts over everyday and lasts for 1 Session. My goal is to make an alternative version having a 3-session long period but always starting its 'longer session' 2 normal sessions ago.

For example, today is Wednesday, so this new VWAP plot should be started at Monday. Tomorrow, I should see it's started at Tuesday. I've made counter for the Sessions (so I could make a 2-days version of it) but I couldn't manage to math this 3-days version out from it.

Comment: I must add that it's not about VWAP. It's about a Boolean variable that controls an indicator; in this case, the VWAP.